# Which is the best package to draw drawings in python?

Tags: software-recommendation, python

We are trying to implement the drawing tools like line, circle, pencil, brush and so on in gtk.

Is it possible to draw these things into the textview? Would one of these packages work for the project?

1. pygame
2. pyglet
3. pycairo

Comment: Maybe this question would fit better in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the packages you listed would work, but I remember using [gtk.gdk.Pixmap()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixmap.html) and [gtk.DrawingArea()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-DrawingArea.html) to draw.